# Can tcp_wrappers be bypassed?

Tags: security

I utilize TCP wrappers to secure services running on my machine.  Things like webmail, cpanel, whostmgrd, and so on.  I use the hosts.allow/hosts.deny files to facilitate this.

Is it possible for an intruder to bypass tcp_wrappers in order to gain access to my services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wouldn't be much value to it if it could be bypassed, now, would it?

There are a number of scenarios in which TCP wrappers might be made ineffective, though.  Misconfiguration is almost certainly the most likely -- a mistaken netmask, misspelling of a service name, and so on.  You might also be running a service which doesn't support TCP wrappers, which is more common than you might think, and not realise it (configure it in `hosts.deny`, but nothing ever happens).  Then there's bugs, which these days I'd consider "unlikely", but you should never discount them completely.